# how to take video from screen?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter-canvas

I want to take a video from screen but it shouldn't use a while loop for taking the picture.I am using tkinter for my GUI.

I have tried after method for taking the picture every time when it needs to be taken. But it doesn't work appropriately. is there any way that I can do it without while true loop?

```
{def recording_loop(out):
   """take video by Imagegrab"""
    img = ImageGrab.grab()
    img_np = np.array(img)
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(img_np, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    out.write(frame)
    self.canvas.after(41, self.recording_loop, res))}
```

I expect that every 41ms the recording_loop revokes itself, so it can take 24 pictures in 1s (frame=24). but it doesn't work. Any help would appreciate.   (out is output of cv2.videowriter(....) )

Comment: what is the specific problem tha you have? why you say that it doesn't work? it doesn't take 24 images or what else? does it raise some errors?

Comment: @Mat.C it create the video file(.avi) but there is no video in it. the volume of that is always 6kb. that's the problem.